# SQL I need help here

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help , there is code of sql , pikt are number , emri is name , I show them all data in a table but i want to show where the pikt(number) are the same I want to order then by emri (name).

```
SELECT emri,mbiemri,mungesat,pikt FROM nxensi ORDER BY pikt DESC
```

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the keyword `DESC / ASC` to both your orders

```
ORDER BY pikt DESC, emri ASC
```

have a look at [ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)